# Does $\int (\sin x)^{\cos x}dx$ exist?

Tags: calculus, integration

> Does this integral exist?
> $$\int (\sin x)^{\cos x}dx$$

I can't find any answers from Wolfram Alpha which stated that the integral does not exist in terms of elementary functions. Is there a way of doing this?

Comment: Exists, or has a nice expression ?

Comment: To be clear: Which of these do you mean? 
$$(a) \int (\sin x)^{\cos x} dx \qquad (b)\int \sin\left(x^{\cos x}\right)dx$$

Comment: The first integral is the one I'm asking. Not necessarily in terms of special functions but does it exist?

Comment: Without getting into complex numbers, if $\sin x<0$ the integrand, never mind its antiderivative, is undefined.

Comment: How about the change of variable $t = \tan (x/2)$ or others? The expression $\exp(\cos x \log \sin x)$ might be easier to handle than $(\sin x)^{\cos x}$.

Comment: You won't get a nice antiderivative if Wolfram couldn't find it (almost surely). You might, with luck, be able to evaluate a definite integral with this integrand over very specific bounds.

Comment: Using $x\to\ln(x)$ gives $\int (\sqrt 2)^{-(x^i+x^{-i})}(i(x^{-i}-x^i))^\frac{x^i+x^{-i}}2\frac{dx}x$. You may try $f^g=\exp(g\ln(f))$. Also, please see [this question guide](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).